# Angular 6 - functions in ngOnInit won't trigger

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

My problem is that in `setStyle()` function, I have the right values for those 2 arrays, but it won't enter on `.map`. Why is that? Where should I call `setStyle()` function in order to trigger `.map`, if not in `ngOnInit`?

```
  ngOnInit() {
      this.existingCustomers = this.trackService.refreshExCusts()
      this.nonExistingCustomers = this.trackService.refreshNonExCusts()
      this.setStyle()
  }

  setStyle() {
    // it enters here
    console.log(this.existingCustomers) // has the right value
    console.log(this.nonExistingCustomers) // has the right value

    this.existingCustomers.map((val) => this.lineStyle.push({ // won't enter here
        "customer": val.customer_name,
        "color": '#000000'
    }))

    this.nonExistingCustomers.map((val) =>  this.lineStyle.push({ // won't enter here
      "customer": val.customer_name,
      "color": '#ff0000'
    }))

    console.log(this.lineStyle) // this is empty
  }
```

The value of the arrays:

`existingCustomers = [{customer_name: "a"}, {customer_name: "b"}]`

`nonExistingCustomers = [{customer_name: "c"}, {customer_name: "d"}]`

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I am thinking that `trackService.refreshExCusts` and the other method as well are asynchronous (return observable or promise) so you have to await the results. Also `map` returns a new altered array which you have to assign to something.

Comment: If `existingCustomers` is an array you're probably looking for `foreach` instead of `map`.

Comment: Is there an error?

Comment: No error, just an empty array (`this.lineStyle = []`)

Comment: Please add a console.log of `this.lineStyle` to the bottom of the setStyle method. Is the correct value present or not?

Comment: No, it's empty.

Comment: @Igor I did as you said and I `await`ed the response, and now I have the right values. I set a timeout of 3 seconds. But how much do I need to wait? How do I know? Why 3, why not 1, or 10 seconds? I don't want to wait much longer that needed.

Comment: Where are you printing `this.lineStyle` to find out it is empty? My suspect is that `map` and `forEach` take call back functions, so there might be the race condition. Try the `for` loop.

Comment: @Tenzolinho You have to provide more details. What does `this.trackService.refreshExCusts()` and `this.trackService.refreshNonExCusts()` return and look like? What type is `this.existingCustomers` and `this.nonExistingCustomers`?

Comment: You should try to enter in debug mode to really see if your arrays are filled when entering the setStyle() method. I suspect that the logs are printed after the promises resolves, but that the `.map` executes before the promises are resolved (which results in your error case)

Comment: Awaiting the result from a promise should not be done by setting a timeout. Read over the suggested duplicate, it is rich in information and should help you better understand how to work with asynchronous callbacks in javascript / typescript.

Comment: To add to @Igor: do NOT use `setTimeout()` or whatever you're using. You cannot guarantee that after the timeout is done, the value will be there. Also, you're not operating at maximum speed; you absolutely need to either `subscribe` to the functions, if they're `Observable`s, or use something like `forkJoin(method1, method2).subscribe((ex, nex) => { this.existingCustomers = ex; this.nonExistingCustomers = nex; this.setStyle()  }`.

Comment: I think it would help everyone if you posted the code for TrackService.

Answer (score 1):

The object arrays are defined incorrectly, they should look like below for your code to work:

```
  existingCustomers = [{ customer_name: "a" }, { customer_name: "b" }];

  nonExistingCustomers = [{ customer_name: "c" }, { customer_name: "d" }];
```

I tested with these arrays, and I get the lineStyle printed in console as:

```
[{"customer":"a","color":"#000000"},{"customer":"b","color":"#000000"},{"customer":"c","color":"#ff0000"},{"customer":"d","color":"#ff0000"}]
```

**UPDATE**: OP Confirmed that the Array definition was typo in the question. So my only other suspect is how the `map` or `forEach` take a callback function and therefore race condition when `console.log` prints the array. Try the `for` loops:

```
  setStyle() {
    // it enters here
    console.log(this.existingCustomers) // has the right value
    console.log(this.nonExistingCustomers) // has the right value

    for (let i = 0; i < this.existingCustomers.length; i++) {
      this.lineStyle.push({ // won't enter here
        "customer": this.existingCustomers[i].customer_name,
        "color": '#000000'
      })
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < this.nonExistingCustomers.length; i++) {
      this.lineStyle.push({ // won't enter here
        "customer": this.nonExistingCustomers[i].customer_name,
        "color": '#ff0000'
      })
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.lineStyle)) // this is empty
  }
```

Comment: I am very sorry, I did a mistake when I wrote the value of those 2 arrays.. they are build like you said.. :( the problem is with the callback for sure

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you are implementing onInit:

```
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
export class Random implements OnInit {
  constructor() { }

  // implement OnInit's `ngOnInit` method
  ngOnInit() { 
     console.log(`OnInit`); 
  }

}
```

Comment: This is not required, as interfaces are a typescript construct they will disappear during compilation. Angular will always call `ngOnInit` if the method is defined, regardless of whether or not the interface was implemented in the source.
https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#interfaces-are-optional-technically

Comment: Good practice though